# Adding only android app to facebook

Tags: android, facebook, google-play

When I added my android game app to facebook, on game page got next instructions:
"To fix this error, please set your Canvas URL and/or Secure Canvas URL".

But what I have to do, if I want publishing without canvas app? What I should do? I know it is possible. But no information about this.

On preview screen game looks nice with button "send to smartphone". How I can enable application?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Okay, there is answer on my question:
Facebook have 2 apps links:

apps.facebook.com/xxxx for Facebook games, which you can play on Facebook canvas (so it is a required field)

facebook.com/games/xxxx for games, there have link to differents platforms (mobile, facebook canvas, etc). So you should post this links at sharing (When you have a mobile game)

thats all. Just another link